# Convert a list to an integer

Tags: concatenation

How can we convert a list to an integer correctly?

**{5, 22, 4, 5} -> 52245?**

When I use the command `FromDigits` in Mathematica

```
FromDigits[{5, 22, 4, 5}]
```

The result is incorrect, namely **7245**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are three ways to do it. The first is the best I think:

```
FromDigits@Flatten[IntegerDigits /@ {5, 22, 4, 5}]

ToExpression@StringJoin[ToString /@ {5, 22, 4, 5}]

ToExpression@StringJoin@StringCases[Characters@ToString@{5, 22, 4, 5}, DigitCharacter]
```

Answer (score 10):

```
FromDigits @ ToString @ Row @ {5, 22, 4, 5}

Head[%]
```

> ```
> 52245
>
> Integer
> ```

Answer (score 5):

```
ToExpression@StringJoin@IntegerString[{5, 22, 4, 5}]
```

> 52245

```
ToExpression@StringJoin@IntegerString[{5, 22, 4, 5},#]&/@{2,10,16}
```

> {10110110100101, 52245, 51645}

Answer (score 4):

```
{5, 22, 4, 5} ~ StringRiffle ~ "" // FromDigits
```

> ```
> 52245
> ```

Comment: Awesome. Never thought of StringRiffle

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {5, 22, 4, 5};
FromDigits[StringJoin[IntegerString[list]]]
```

which gives

```
52245
```